# Is it possible to find the least common divisor of a two numbers that are not relatively prime in polynomial time?

Tags: asymptotics, divisibility

As the question states:

Is it possible to find the least common divisor of two number that are not relatively prime in polynomial time? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Least common divisor other than one?

Comment: "least" common divisor?

Comment: Yes, least common divisor greater than one.

Comment: Smallest common prime factor, in other words.

Comment: Exactly. Can that be calculated in polynomial time?

Comment: You can find the $\gcd$ in polynomial time, and then the task is to find the smallest prime factor of some number in polynomial time. If the $\gcd$ happens to be prime, or have a small prime factor, that's easy. In general, that would mean you have a fast factorisation algorithm. As far as I know, there is no known algorithm to find the smallest prime factor of a number in polynomial time.

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you very much.

Comment: If we had a good "least common divisor $\gt 1$" algorithm, applying it to $(N,N)$ where $N$ is big would give us a good factoring algorithm.

Comment: @AndreNicolas : why don't you make that into an answer, and combine it with the fact that (I am pretty sure) no one knows if such an algorithm exists?

Comment: @Stefan Smith: It is already implicitly contained in the comment by Daniel Fischer. If no one answers for a fair while, and I can find the question again, I can make a CW answer.

Comment: @StefanSmith, I think it's pretty much certain that if anyone had published such an algorithm then we'd all have heard about it. Of course, that doesn't mean the NSA doesn't have one hidden away somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the answer is no. There is a heuristic why it should be hard in general. Namely, the least common divisor divides the greatest common divisor. The greatest common divisor is calculable in log time. We then would want to calculate the smallest divisor $> 1$ of the gcd. But if the gcd is a hard to factor number, we're out of luck.

More generally, if we had such a technique, then we would also be able to factor in polynomial time. While this might yet be possible (in the sense that we haven't proved it's impossible), it's not likely and certainly not currently known. As Andre Nicolas said in the comments, we would apply the least-common-divisor operator to $(N,N)$, which would spit out a factor. Repeating, we could completely factor $N$.

As an aside, it is sometimes common for factoring algorithms to take the gcd of $N$ and the product of the first $40$ primes or so, to get all the small primes out of the way. This is fast, and so we can find small prime divisors quickly. But this is a different question.